# python how to see data in file object .obj

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I would like see data in file `.obj`, but I keep getting error.
This is my code

```
infile = open('tfidf_vect_obj.obj','rb'))
print(infile)
```

Please, help me fix this issue

Comment: Please provide more informaiton

Comment: "*I keep getting error*": What is the error? Please [edit] to post the *full* error message. It's probably related to the extra `)` at the end of `...obj','rb'))`

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use ?

```
with open("tfidf_vect_obj.obj", "rb") as file:
    file = ........
```

Comment: It would be helpful to the OP if you explain *why* your code works.

Answer (score 0):

With `open()` you will get the file as an object. Then you can retrieve the data by using methods defined for that file object, like `read()` for example.

```
infile = open('tfidf_vect_obj.obj','rb')
data = infile.read()
print(data)
infile.close()
```

By using a context manager (with statement), you don't have to care about closing the file at the end:

```
with open('tfidf_vect_obj.obj','rb') as infile:
    data = infile.read()
    print(data)
```

You can see more about this topic in the official [Python tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).